# Is it permitted to have a boy under barmitzvah age sing Anim Zemiros?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minhag, minor-katan-child, chazzan-prayer-leader

Is it permitted to have a boy under barmitzvah age sing the Shir Hakavod (or Anim Zemiros)? Why is it not like any other part of davenning where we use someone over barmitzvah?

Comment: Apparently it is permitted, the question is why it should be.

Comment: I have been to Shuls where children say the Pesukai D'Zimra also. So long that there is no Kaddish or Kedusha which requires an adult, a child can say the Tefila in the role of a Chazan.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Rambam ([Hilchot Tefilla chap. 9](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920172/jewish/Chapter-Nine.htm)), only the following sections of davening (prayer services) require a Chazzan [over Bar Mitzvah]:

- Kaddish
- Birchot Kriat Shema
- Shemona Esrei, Chazart haShatz, and Kedusha
- Tachanun, Ashrei and Uva L'Tzion

In addition, if a part of davening doesn't require a minyan, it would make sense that a minor could lead it.  Pseukei D'zimra and [Anim Zemirot don't require a minyan](http://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/halacha-hashkafa/anim-z%E2%80%99mirot-part-l/2011/11/17/), so it follows that a child could be chazzan.

Comment: Source TBA for my second assertion ("in addition...").  If you know one, please let me know\add it to the answer.

Comment: I believe Ben Ish Hai holds that Hashem Melech and Baruch SheAmar should also be said by a bar mitzvaed person.

Comment: @Shmuel What about Krias haTorah?

Comment: @DannySchoemann That doesn't need a Chazzan. It requires Olim.

Answer (score 3):

[From Wikipedia:](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93)

> בבתי כנסת הנוהגים שהחזן קורא שורה והקהל קוראים שורה, נהוג לתת את
>   החזנות לילד קטן (מתחת לגיל בר מצווה). יש הטוענים כי הסיבה לכך היא שרק
>   ילד קטן ותמים יכול לדבר אל הקב"ה בצורה כה ישירה.

Translation:

In shuls where it is the custom to read the song responsively, it is customary to allow a child to be Chazzan.  There are those who explain that this is because only an innocent child is able to speak to God in such a direct and forthright manner.

Comment: Rabbi Barry Freundel repeatedly quoted Chasidei Ashkenaz, as authors of this prayer, saying that innocent children are the ideal leaders of this prayer.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a machlokes among the contemporary poskim. See [Dose of Halacha](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/children-and-pesicha.html):

> R’ Moshe Sternbuch (Teshuvos Vehanhagos 2:81) holds that it is inappropriate for a child to lead anim zemiros.
>
> Nonetheless, R’ Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (12:96) held that a child may do so (See Ishei Yisrael 36:n196). Many shuls follow this, especially as they want to encourage child participation at the end of davening.